# Apply format to column in listView depending on Name Column

Tags: xml, visual-studio, listview, wpf-controls, listviewitem

I'm actually developing a WPF Desktop Application on Visual Basic and my problem is that I've been trying to set some format to some columns into a listView without success, so I was wondering if someone could help or head me in the right direction

I want to set format like text aligment to respective columns, and I was triying to do this through the xml interface depending on column name, maybe I should be trying through the .vb code?

thanks